# What is RFC 401's coerce_inner useful for?

Tags: rust, coercion

I'm reading Rust's [RFC 0401](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0401-coercions.md) and see this:

> coerce_inner(`Foo<..., T, ...>`) = `Foo<..., coerce_inner(T), ...>` where `Foo` is a struct and only the last field has type `T` and `T` is not part of the type of any other fields;
>
> coerce_inner(`(..., T)`) = `(..., coerce_inner(T))`.

It this up-to-date information? If so, what is this useful for?

Answer (score 0):

They are used to turn a struct/tuple with sized "tail" into an unsized one.